# Existence of Laurent series $\frac{1}{1+e^{1/z}}$ around $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Trying to sum a series by writing it as the residue of a complex function, I was led to the following function

\begin{align*}
f(z) = \frac{e^{-az-\frac{b}{z}}}{z}n(z)n\left(z^{-1}\right)
\end{align*}
where $a,b\in[0,1)$ are real constants and  $n(z) = \left(e^{z}+1\right)^{-1}$. $f(z)$ has poles at $z=\pi(2n+1)$ due to $n(z)$ and at $z=\frac{1}{\pi(2n+1)}$ due to $n(1/z)$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Further, it has an essential singularity at $z=0$. I would like to compute the residue at $z=0$. My thought was to look at the Laurent series of each term around $z=0$, but I am struggling with the factor $n(1/z)$.

As a real function $n(1/x)$, it has a well defined limit as $x\to 0$. However at any complex neighbourhood of $z=0$ (say a punctured circle  of radius $\epsilon>0$) there $\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{1}{\pi(2n+1)}<\epsilon$, i.e. there are always infinitely many poles in the neighbourhood.

Does that mean the Laurent series around $z=0$ does not exist?

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the sad conclusion: there is no annulus $\;0<|z|<r\;,\;\;r>0\;$ in which the given function is analytic.

Comment: @DonAntonio, no hope for the integral then? I never faced such a situation before, specially because the problem come from physical motivation.

Comment: @Kr What integral? If you succeed in taking an integral around some region where the function is either analytic or at least has only isolated poles then you can do it. If it is a circle centered at the origin, say, then the integral doesn't exist...

Comment: @DonAntonio, sorry for being vague. The original aim was to compute the 'fourier like' series defined by the residues of the poles of $n(z)$: $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-a z_n-\frac{b}{z_n}}n(1/z_n)$ for $z_n=i\pi(2n+1)$. Any suggestion welcome.

Comment: @Ku I really don't know  how numbers, which is what residues are, can define Fourier series, which are for *functions* .

Comment: @DonAntonio, the series I wrote above, which is the sum over the residues of $f(z)$ around $z_n$ defines a function of $a,b\in (0,1)$. Calling 'fourier-like' might have been misleading.